# Question visibility and reputation

Tags: support, reputation, flagging, policy, views

I wonder whether the visibility of a post changes according to the user's reputation asking the question. Is it also known if a user's posts' visibility is affected by other actions, like having *mistakenly* flagged a question, an answer, or a comment as inappropriate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on where you're looking, but in general, the visibility is **only** determined by the timestamp (either of the last activity, or of the moment the question was created). However, on the homepage, questions with a score of -4 and lower are hidden. In any case, reputation doesn't matter; Stack Exchange is all about the content, not the person who wrote it.

Your flags don't have anything to do with whether your questions are visible or not. (With a reputation of 11, you can't even flag anything except your own posts, FWIW.)

Comment: Perhaps "the Stack Exchange _software_ is all about the content, not the person who wrote it"—the community, in which I include myself, definitely does not react to content in a manner that is blind to its author.  (And I think that if it were all about the content in the deepest possible way, then author names wouldn't even be shown.)  For example, I trust this Meta answer more when I see it's from you; from someone else I might wonder if they fully understood the system.